# How to make profile default for docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with 2 exclusive profiles `local` and `dev`, which we use for local testing and pulling the dev environment down for debugging.

Is there a way to default to `local` so that we can use `docker-compose build` without specifying `--profile` and docker will default to `local`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use the [COMPOSE_PROFILES](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_profiles) environment variable. To always have it set, you could put:

`COMPOSE_PROFILES=local` in */etc/environment*

or...

`export COMPOSE_PROFILES=local` in *~/.bashrc* or *~/.zshrc*

Then restart your shell. You can type this to ensure your shell has picked up the env var:

`echo $COMPOSE_PROFILES`

Comment: Yes, and to switch to the dev profile, you can temporarily change the COMPOSE_PROFILES variable: `COMPOSE_PROFILES=dev docker-compose up`: This will enable the `dev` profile for that single command, without changing your default `local` profile.

Comment: Good answer - still a shame that there's no way to do this in files, and setting `COMPOSE_PROFILES` variable will require user pre-action.  It would be great to be able to have this-or-that profile with a default, rather than the current default profile which is empty and can't be easily switched-off.

Comment: Even better, you can set that variable in that specific project's `.env` file. Setting it for the use implies that the user only works on a single project.

Answer (score 9):

I was just playing with this; it turns out that services using an empty string as a profile will be started when a profile is not specified but, unlike those without a profile, not when another profile is.

While it should be noted that this isn't documented, so the functionality may change in the future, I reckon it should be sufficient to implement a decent "default" profile functionality for situations the `COMPOSE_PROFILES` variable doesn't suffice.

E.g.

```yaml
services:
    a:
        image: busybox
        profiles:
            - ''
    b:
        image: busybox
        profiles:
            - ''
            - a
    c:
        image: busybox
        profiles:
            - a
```

```shell
aj@laptop:~/test$ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container test-b-1  Created                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container test-a-1  Created                          0.0s 
Attaching to test-a-1, test-b-1
test-a-1 exited with code 0
test-b-1 exited with code 0

aj@laptop:~/test$ docker compose --profile a up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container test-c-1  Created                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container test-b-1  Created                          0.0s 
Attaching to test-b-1, test-c-1
test-b-1 exited with code 0
test-c-1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: The trick with the empty profile name seems to no longer work.

Comment: @AdSR What version is not not working for you with?  Just checked and it's working for me on `24.0.6`

Comment: 20.10.23 - I'm guessing that's pretty old.

Comment: Released a bit under 3 years ago, but it's still supported.  I wonder when the empty profile name behaviour came in and how intentional it was.

Comment: I am using Docker Desktop Windows 23.0.5. Empty profile doesn't work. Says "no service selected"

Answer (score -1):

You can use profiles in the new version. `docker compose up` will run services with missing `profiles` setting.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web1:
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    ports:
      - "4001:5678"
    command: -text='hello 1'

  web2:
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    ports:
      - "4002:5678"
    command: -text='hello 2'
    profiles:
      - some-profile
```

To run the first default service:

```
docker compose up
```

To run the second service:

```
docker compose up web2
```

There are downsides:

If you run `docker compose --profile some-profile up` the services that do not have profiles attributes will be started as well.

Comment: OP was explicitly asking about having a profile be default, not about having services not in a profile start by default.